# Where are my files when i create one using python

Tags: python

So I started Creating a python script to learn how creating and writing txt files work in python

Here is the script:

```
f = open("my.abc", "x")
f.write("Added more content")
f.close()

#open and read the file after the appending:
f = open("my.abc", "r")
print(f.read())
```

And when I run it for the first  time:

```
Added more content
```

And when I run it the second time:

```
Added more contentAdded more content
```

But in the directory the Script I wrote is in, there is no file with the same name.

```
D:\python>dir
 Volume in drive D is Python

 Directory of D:\python

01/01/1970  00:00 PM    <DIR>          .
01/01/1970  00:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/01/1970  00:00 PM               157 test.py
               1 File(s)            xxx bytes
               2 Dir(s)  xxx bytes free
```

So I was wondering where are these file being saved?

Comment: They are put *in the place you told them to be put*. `f = open("my.abc", "x")` opens the file at `"my.abc"`, however that is interpreted as a *relative path from your working directory*. It is almost always better to use an absolute path to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Usually that is the folder where your script is unless a *cd* happens somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can find your current working directory through:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

this should be where your files are saved if you do not specify a path.